# validate_on_submit() from Flask-WTF always returns true

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm using Flask-WTF's validate_on_submit() function for very simple one-page website in a such code:

```
class SignForm(FlaskForm):
    testStrField = StringField("enter some text data")
    doCheckSign = SubmitField('Check the signed data')

@AppEDS1.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index1():
    form = SignForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ....
```

In my `<form></form>` there are also some buttons with separate JS-handlers for onclick events, and I noticed that each POST-request to my site triggers validate_on_submit() in the way it returns TRUE for each request.
Actually, the only difference between requests is in corresponding Request Payload sections:

(for the "just-onclick-POST-request")
*csrf_token=blablabla&testStrField=*

(for the "sumbit-POST-request")
*csrf_token=blablablabla&testStrField=ggggggggggg&doCheckSign=Check+the+signed+data*

So my question is - how actually validate_on_submit() determines whether it was "submit POST request" (have to return TRUE) or just-any-POST-request to website-backend (have to return FALSE but it doesn't)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this example](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html#module-flask_wtf.file), you don't specify any requirement about your form. It should be like:

```py
class SignForm(FlaskForm):
    testStrField = StringField(validators=[InputRequired()])
    doCheckSign = SubmitField(validators=[InputRequired()])
```

Comment: yes, but I haven't any requirements for my form's data